# Integrate SOAP UI with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, testing, automation, soapui

I need to integrate Soap UI and Eclipse and execute test scenarios from eclipse which will also execute the webservice test from Soap UI,I am unable to download SoapUI plugin for Eclipse,Please help with details what I need to do to set up the same...Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Only possible way to download soupui-eclipse-plugin from http://sourceforge.net/projects/soapui/files/soapui-eclipse-plugin/ and install.
I am sorry there are no other ways. Thanks

Comment: @isurujay...thanks...but if ther is anyway to code it and get things done